# Vba: Automate the selection of a cell using match function on the just upper row composed of dates

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a beginner with Vba

I want to automate the selection of a cell depending on the current date. For this purpose, I have the values I want to select on row 8 and the dates in chronological order on row 7.

I tried the following code:

```
Sub selectvalues()

Dim rtc As Double
Dim ystdy As Date
Dim tdy As Date

szToday = Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD")
tdy = szToday
ystdy = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(tdy, -1)

rtc = WorksheetFunction.Match(ystdy, Range("A7", "ZZ7"), 0)

Cells(8, rtc).Select


End Sub
```

But I get

> 13 error on execution time, types doesn't match

Could anyone help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You try to assign a string to a date by tdy = szToday

Comment: `szToday` is a string and you are trying to put a string into a date when you write `tdy = szToday`. So, of course it fails. Use instead `tdy = Date`. In order to avoid such problems in the future I'd recommend you make use of `Option Explicit` (Search for it if you don't know what it is or means.)

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you've suggested removing szTdoay and modifying tdy :

`tdy = Date`

But now I get the 1004 error: "error defined by the application of the object"

Comment: Hi @Mauro, you may want to double check your variables and make sure you have assigned them the proper data type. Also, you should take some time to look around to fill in the gaps. With a little bit of research and working through each error one-by-one you should be able to work through it.

[What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254572/what-is-the-proper-way-to-approach-stack-overflow-as-someone-totally-new-to-prog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, since you are looking to find a certain value in a row, the `Find` function could work better.

Try the code below, explanations inside the code's comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub selectvalues()

Dim rtc As Variant
Dim ystdy As Date
Dim tdy As Date
Dim FindRng As Range

tdy = Date
ystdy = WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(tdy, -1)

' use Find function 
Set FindRng = Range("A7", "ZZ7").Find(What:=ystdy, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then ' see that find was successful
    FindRng.Select
Else
    MsgBox "Error, unable to match " & ystdy & " in the specified range", vbCritical
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll find out more aboute Set functionalitie, I don't know why is difficult for me to understand it well.

Comment: Is defining rtc as Variant neccesary? I don't find utility for this on the code. Thanks

Comment: @Mauro I like to declare all of my objects and variables, you can try without it and see what happens